# I have an issue with my logic in this SASS for loop using two lists.... the error I'm getting says "index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`"

Tags: css, list, sass, media-queries

Here's my code:

```
$responsive-adjust-amounts: (
2.5, //phone
2,   //tablet
1.5, //laptop
1.25 //desktop
);

$responsive-devices: ("#{$phone}", "#{$tablet}", "#{$laptop}", "#{$desktop}");

@each $device in $responsive-devices {
    @media #{$device} {
        @for $i from 1 through length($responsive-adjust-amounts) {
            @media #{$device} {
                #{nth($responsive-adjust-amounts, $i)} {
                    @include font-adjustments(nth($responsive-adjust-amounts, $i));
                }
            }
            $i: $i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I'm wanting it to create this end result:

```
@media #{$phone} {
    @include font-adjustments(nth($responsive-adjust-amounts, 1));
}

@media #{$tablet} {
    @include font-adjustments(nth($responsive-adjust-amounts, 2));
}

@media #{$laptop} {
    @include font-adjustments(nth($responsive-adjust-amounts, 3));
}

@media #{$desktop} {
    @include font-adjustments(nth($responsive-adjust-amounts, 4));
}
```

Could anyone provide any assistance where I'm getting stuck? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Excitedly, I've solved my own problem just now.  Here's how:

```
@each $device in $responsive-devices {
    $i: index($responsive-devices, #{$device});
    @media #{$device} {
        @include font-adjustments(nth($responsive-adjust-amounts, $i))
    }
}
```

Additionally, I forgot to include the font-adjustments mixin in the original post.  So here is that for anyone's review if needed in the future:

```
@mixin font-adjustments($amount) {
    body {font-size: ($body-base * $amount)}
    h4 {font-size: ($subhead-base * $amount)}
    h1 {font-size: ($h1-base * $amount)}
}
```